# WSO2: My keystore is added to carbon, but does not load at startup

Tags: security, ssl, wso2, certificate

I am trying to make my wso2 server on my VPS secure, so I ordered a certificate as prescribed by my provider Hostnet.nl, than created and added a keystore as described by wso2 on https://www.yenlo.com/blog/setting-up-wso2-with-a-valid-certificate. Last step was to modify carbon.xml, in which I added my keystore

```
<KeyStore>
    <!-- Keystore file location-->
    <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/MijnWSO2sleutelwinkel.jks</Location>
    <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
    <Type>JKS</Type>
    <!-- Keystore password-->
    <Password>mypassword</Password>
    <!-- Private Key alias-->
    <KeyAlias>mijnWSO2sleutelwinkel</KeyAlias>
    <!-- Private Key password-->
    <KeyPassword>mypassword</KeyPassword>
</KeyStore>
```

Upon restarting the VPS and WSO2 the keystore did not appear in /carbon in the list of keystores. I was able to add it manually by uploading the keystore file and the SSL_CA file of the intermediary party, Hostnet. Looks fine in Carbon's list of keystores, but after restarting the VPS and WSO2, the keystore does not get loaded. In the startup script of WSO2 I only see wso2carbon getting loaded:

```
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,106]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,122]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,128]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder customSSLProfiles configuration is loaded from path: /usr/local/opt/wso2am-2.2.0/repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,128]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading custom SSL profiles for the HTTPS sender
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,129]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,130]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,132]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Custom SSL profiles initialized for 1 servers
[2018-05-22 15:24:27,133]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
```

And no further mentions of SSL or my own keystore at all. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you comment out or remove the default KeyStore config element in carbon.xml?

Comment: Nope and that indeed made the difference. Carbon now correctly finds my keystore. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions given in the same link - 
https://www.yenlo.com/blog/setting-up-wso2-with-a-valid-certificate

I am able to find all of the files to change the .jks except for the last reference -

```
./security/secret-conf.properties:21:#keystore.identity.location=repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
```

I am installing the cert on a APIM 2.2 server, is this file deprecated in this new version?